# Dynamic delegates in Polly’s Fallback

Tags: c#, .net, fallback, transient, polly

I have the following policy in a PolicyRegistry to be reused globally:

```
var fallbackPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<DrmException>().OrInner<DrmException>()
        .Fallback(
            fallbackAction: () => { //should commit or dispose the transaction here using a passed in Func or Action },
            onFallback: (exception) => { Log.Error().Exception(exception).Message($"Exception occurred, message: {exception.Message}.").Write(); }
        );
```

I have the following code which I want to implement the `fallbackPolicy` in:

```
   if(Settings.DRM_ENABLED)
       drmManager.ExecuteAsync(new DeleteUser(123).Wait();//HTTP Call, throws DrmException if unsuccessful

       //in some cases, there is an if(transaction == null) here (if transaction was passed as a parameter and needs to be committed here)
       transaction.Commit();//if not thrown - commits the transaction
```

I would like it to look something like this:

```
var fallbackPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<DrmException>().OrInner<DrmException>()
            .Fallback(
                fallbackAction: (transaction) => { transaction.Dispose(); },
                onFallback: (exception) => { Log.Error().Exception(exception).Message($"Exception occurred, message: {exception.Message}.").Write(); }
            );    

fallbackPolicy.Execute(() => drmManager.ExecuteAsync(new DeleteUser(123).Wait(), transaction)
```

As far as I understand the `fallbackPolicy.Execute` takes Action/Func to be carried out which either succeeds, in which case the `fallbackPolicy` is not hit, or fails, in which case the `fallbackPolicy` kicks in with some predefined `fallbackAction`.

What I would like to do is to pass in two handlers (`onFail(transaction)` which disposes the transaction and `onSuccess(transaction)` which commits the transaction) when executing the policy. Is there an easier way of doing it instead of wrapping it or using a Polly's context?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Show us what you've tried, why it didn’t meet your needs and any error messages. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't see how this is dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic in a way that the policy caller could provide the policy with a fallbackAction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feels like there are a few separate questions here:

1. **How can I make a centrally-defined FallbackPolicy do something dynamic?**
2. **How can I make one FallbackPolicy do two things?**
3. **With Polly in the mix, how can I do one thing on overall failure and another on overall success?**

I'll answer these separately to give you a full toolkit to build your own solution - and for future readers - but you'll probably not need all three to achieve your goal.  Cut to **3.** if you just want a solution.

**1. How can I make a centrally-defined FallbackPolicy do something dynamic?**

For any policy defined centrally, yes `Context` is the way you can pass in something specific for that execution.  References: [discussion in a Polly issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/292); [blog post](http://www.thepollyproject.org/2017/05/04/putting-the-context-into-polly/).

Part of your q seems around making the `FallbackPolicy` both log; and deal with the transaction. So ...

**2. How can I make one FallbackPolicy do two things?**

You can pass in something dynamic (per above).  Another option is use two different fallback policies.  You can [use the same kind of policy multiple times in a PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap#using-the-same-type-of-policy-more-than-once-in-a-wrap).  So you could define a centrally-stored `FallbackPolicy` to do just the logging, and keep it simple, non-dynamic:

```
var loggingFallbackPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<DrmException>().OrInner<DrmException>()
    .Fallback(fallbackAction: () => { /* maybe nothing, maybe rethrow - see discussion below */ },
         onFallback: (exception) => { /* logging; */ });
```

Then you can define another `FallbackPolicy` locally to roll back the transaction on failure.  Since it's defined locally, you could likely just pass the `transaction` variable in to its `fallbackAction:` using a closure (in which case you don't have to use `Context`).

*Note:* If using two `FallbackPolicy`s in a `PolicyWrap`, you'd need to make the inner `FallbackPolicy` *rethrow* (not swallow) the handled exception, so that the outer `FallbackPolicy` also handles it.

---

Re:

> What I would like to do is to pass in two handlers (`onFail(transaction)` which
>   disposes the transaction and `onSuccess(transaction)` which commits the transaction)

There isn't any policy which offers special handling on success, but:

**3. With Polly in the mix, how can I do one thing on overall failure and another on overall success?**

Use [`.ExecuteAndCapture(...)`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception).  This returns a `PolicyResult` with property `.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful` or `OutcomeType.Failure` (and other info: see [documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#post-execution-capturing-the-result-or-any-final-exception))

So overall, something like:

```
var logAndRethrowFallbackPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<DrmException>().OrInner<DrmException>()
    .Fallback(fallbackAction: (exception, context, token) => { 
        throw exception; // intentional rethrow so that the 'capture' of ExecuteAndCapture reacts.  Use ExceptionDispatchInfo if you care about the original call stack.
        },
        onFallback: (exception, context) => { /* logging */ });
```

At execution site:

```
PolicyResult result = myPolicies.ExecuteAndCapture(() => ... ); // where myPolicies is some PolicyWrap with logAndRethrowFallbackPolicy outermost
if (result.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful)
    { transaction.Commit(); }
else
    { transaction.Dispose(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Looks like the solution, but let me get back to you after I try implementing it.

Comment: ExecuteAndCapture with rethrow did the trick, thank you for the solution.